# Highstocks, line missing but data is there

Tags: highcharts

I've been playing around with Highstocks for a while now and for some reason one of my lines has disappeared when zooming in, yet it is still visible once zoomed out. It still shows the dot once hovering over it including the data that belongs to it.

Needless to say I'm pretty clueless about what went wrong, so any suggestions would be great.

Zoomed in:
[image: Zoomed in]

Zoomed out (hard to see but the red line is there)

[image: Zoomed out]

PS. Website can be found here [Skami.net](http://www.skami.net/)

Comment: can you provide the data and a jsfiddle with the same

Comment: Try to update Highstock to 1.3, make sure you don't have anywhere strings as values, and data is sorted ascending.

Comment: Updated to 1.3.1, didn't resolve the issue, and the JSON is valid without any strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series contains doubled values for the same data, for example:

```
    [1368450000000, null], 
    [1368450000000, 117.200050354004], 
    [1368451800000, null],
    [1368451800000, 117.599990844727],
    [1368453600000, null],
    [1368453600000, 117.710151672363]
```

Which is not allowed in Highcharts. Remove extra point and will be working fine.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, I can't believe I messed up that bad >.<

Answer (score 0):

I advice to disable dataGrouping

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: That didn't fix it, it also wouldn't explain why it this doesn't occur on my other charts and that this chart didn't have any issues before.

Comment: So could you prepare example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XT7YZ/ , Once you zoom into to 1 day the line disappears, but it only happens for the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example, points are not rendered, when having points with a null-value. Example from today (taken from [Skami.net](http://www.Skami.net)):

```
[1369881000000,131.74983215332],
[1369882800000,null],
[1369884600000,null],
[1369886400000,131.354995727539],
[1369888200000,null],
[1369890000000,null],
[1369891800000,130.976699829102]
```

The points above will be visible in the tooltip, but not rendered as a graph, because points with a null-value is in between the point with a value.

Comment: Although very true, this wasn't the question, non the less this answer could be useful for some people.

Comment: Yes I know, I had to create an answer, because I could not create a comment - strange... My answer is actually valid for why your graph is not displaying, no duplicate entries in your data, but graph is still missing (as you showed with screenshots). I tried to edit the accepted answer, and that is being peer-reviewed now.