# Issue with Highcharts series addPoint - spline/line - markers visible, but line disappears

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I've been struggling with this issue for a while, and maybe I can get some help.  I have a series of 5 containers with small graphs in each container.  As long as data is static, it displays fine.  However, as soon as I switch to poll live data every three seconds, using series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true), the marker shows up, but the line disappears.  I've researched and tried everything I could find online.  Anyone else having this issue, and how did you fix it?

Here's the code portion I'm performing the addPoint...

```
 array = renameArrayNameKeys(modemNickNameArray, tmpmodem);
 var utxpDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Where(function(x) {
   return x.Name == utxpChart.series[0].name
 }).Select(function(x) {
   return x
 }).ToArray();
 var urxlDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Where(function(x) {
   return x.Name == urxlChart.series[0].name
 }).Select(function(x) {
   return x
 }).ToArray();
 var usnrDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Where(function(x) {
   return x.Name == usnrChart.series[0].name
 }).Select(function(x) {
   return x
 }).ToArray();
 var dsnrDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Where(function(x) {
   return x.Name == dsnrChart.series[0].name
 }).Select(function(x) {
   return x
 }).ToArray();
 var drxlDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Where(function(x) {
   return x.Name == drxlChart.series[0].name
 }).Select(function(x) {
   return x
 }).ToArray();
 var tableDataSet = Enumerable.From(tmpmodem).Select(function(x) {
   return {
     Name: x.Name,
     Color: x.Color,
     Average: x.Value,
     Value: x.Value,
     high: x.high,
     low: x.low
   }
 }).ToArray();
 if (tableDataSet != null) {
   $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.previewType.dataSet = tableDataSet;
   safeApply($scope);
 }
 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
   // current time
   y = parseFloat(utxpDataSet[0].Value);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.utxpChart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.utxpChart.series[0].options.color = utxpDataSet[0].Color;
 var l = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.utxpChart.series[0].points.length;
 var point = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.utxpChart.series[0].points[l - 1];
 point.update({
   marker: {
     fillColor: utxpDataSet[0].Color
   }
 });


 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
   // current time
   y = parseFloat(urxlDataSet[0].Value);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.urxlChart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.urxlChart.series[0].options.color = urxlDataSet[0].Color;
 l = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.urxlChart.series[0].points.length;
 point = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.urxlChart.series[0].points[l - 1];
 point.update({
   marker: {
     fillColor: urxlDataSet[0].Color
   }
 });


 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
   // current time
   y = parseFloat(usnrDataSet[0].Value);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.usnrChart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.usnrChart.series[0].options.color = usnrDataSet[0].Color;
 l = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.usnrChart.series[0].points.length;
 point = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.usnrChart.series[0].points[l - 1];
 point.update({
   marker: {
     fillColor: usnrDataSet[0].Color
   }
 });


 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
   // current time
   y = parseFloat(dsnrDataSet[0].Value);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.dsnrChart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.dsnrChart.series[0].options.color = dsnrDataSet[0].Color;
 l = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.dsnrChart.series[0].points.length;
 point = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.dsnrChart.series[0].points[l - 1];
 point.update({
   marker: {
     fillColor: dsnrDataSet[0].Color
   }
 });


 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
   // current time
   y = parseFloat(drxlDataSet[0].Value);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.drxlChart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
 $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.drxlChart.series[0].options.color = time[0].Color;
 l = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.drxlChart.series[0].points.length;
 point = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.drxlChart.series[0].points[l - 1];
 point.update({
   marker: {
     fillColor: time[0].Color
   }
 });
```

And after the first point is added, the line stops drawing like so...

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJOy.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting null values between your data points?  Can you console.log the x,y for your addPoint to verify the data being set?  This code would be easier to read if these $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.preview.usnrChart were assigned to variables.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? Maybe [`gapSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.gapSize) kicks in? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516683/highstocks-line-missing-but-data-is-there).

Comment: Barbara, you were right.  There was null values being picked up.  I perform a try catch to get all values through an API, and I had a typo in adding the points, where somehow it was adding in time[0].Color.  Guess that's what I get for bulk copy/pasting.  once I changed it to drxlDataSet[0].Color, the points were correctly placed.  Thanks for all your help.